# showing one-to-many as one-to-one from Core Data

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, core-data

I have a relationship of Contacts of people which have one to many relationship of phone numbers.

However, I need to show each contact with different phone number in tableView Cells, so I am not sure after doing fetched results how can I do that?

Currently, this is my logic to get multiple same contacts for different phone numbers.

```
for (Contact *contact in fetchedRecords)
    {
        for (Phone *phone in contact.phoneNumbers)
        {
            [multipleContacts addObject:contact];
        }

    }
```

However, I think there would be a better way to fetch such records of Contact to get result with each phone number entry.

Comment: Could you add more detail about how you want it to be displayed? It sounds like you want to display each contact that has unique phone number.

Comment: Its more like show each contact which have a number, it can be different number with same person. How can this be achieved via NSPredicate?

Comment: Can we assume the relationship is `Phone`<<-->`Contact` (contact may have many phone numbers, but a phone number has a single contact)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to do what you're asking would be to fetch `Phone` objects instead of `Contact` objects. That way, each row in your tableView will correspond to a `Phone` and you can then follow the inverse relationship from `Phone` to `Contact` to get the name to display.

Comment: The inverse relationship worked for me in this case. Thanks @Clever